# Slider control is deactivated when i reopen my workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two problem with Excel 2007:

1 - I created a slider Control (Microsoft Slider control version 6.0) but when i close Excel and open my workbook again, the Slider control is not recognized or desabled. This is strange cause i don't have this problem when i open the same workbook in Excel 2010.

2 - To fix the problem i decided to create my slider control with VBA.

```
*ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="MSComctlLib.Slider.2", link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=27, Top:=166.5, Width:=380.25, Height:= 26.25).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1.08, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
Selection.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 11.25
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -17.25
Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1.11, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft*
```

I don't know why but the Slider Control is not directly activated (as if the control was in design mode). I manage to make the control works by first activate the "design mode", then desable it. I tried to use the update property (Slider21.Update) but i got an error (1004)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. But it is solved after installing 2007 Office SP3.

Download link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27838

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The workbook file will be used by several people, so if i could avoid an update it will be great.

Comment: Others dont have update on their pc! Its free and it is supposed to be installed for bug free usage of office 2007.